# How to include empty rows in Access query results

Tags: ms-access

I have an Access 2010 database with client information. I need to create a table of the number of clients in each age. The agency I am reporting to wants a report with the number of clients of every age from 0 - 100 years listed. The SQL query below will create the required report, but does not include ages with zero clients.

```
SELECT AgeNum & " years" AS [Age], Count(*) AS [Count]
FROM (SELECT Int(DateDiff("d", Clients.dob, now())/365.25) AS AgeNum 
FROM Clients)  AS [%$##@_Alias]
GROUP BY [%$##@_Alias].AgeNum;
```

How can I have the query return the empty rows with 0 in the Count column?

I looked around and found this:

[How can I create a row for values that don't exist and fill the count with 0 values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27162465/how-can-i-create-a-row-for-values-that-dont-exist-and-fill-the-count-with-0-val)

They create a table of values to lookup the empty groups. It is very similar to what I need except it uses a Coalesce function which is not supported in Access 2010.

Comment: `%$##@_Alias` Interesting choice of name!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The system only knows there is an age if a particular record exists. If you want to have a list of age between 1..100, you need to tell or provide the system that you are looking for 0..100 ages. By providing a list of ages you are looking for, system will automatically return 0/null if the requested age is not found withing your searched records.

As others mentioned, you can have a table with 1..100 as rows and compare them in your SQL or you could generate list of numbers with SQL.

Some DBMS provide a default table called dual which has one column and one row, you can use that table for any queries that does not have a from table. 
In your access application, **create a table called "dual" and insert one row**.

Now execute this query:

```
SELECT TMain.counter
FROM (SELECT (T2.mAge*t3.mFactor10)+t1.mAge AS counter
FROM (select 1 as mAge from dual
union all select 2 from dual
union all select 3 from dual
union all select 4 from dual
union all select 5 from dual
union all select 6 from dual
union all select 7 from dual
union all select 8 from dual
union all select 9 from dual
union all select 10 from dual)  AS T1, 
(select 0 as mAge from dual
union all select 1 from dual
union all select 2 from dual
union all select 3 from dual
union all select 4 from dual
union all select 5 from dual
union all select 6 from dual
union all select 7 from dual
union all select 8 from dual
union all select 9 from dual
union all select 10 from dual)  AS T2,
(select 10 as mFactor10 from dual) AS T3 )  AS TMain
WHERE (((TMain.counter) Between 1 And 100));
```

this will produce 100 rows from 1..100.

you can then use this result as outer table for your SQL and find/count anyone whose age is on this list.
the logic would be:

```
select all age 
from the reqeusted age list
find  and count/return all matched records or return 0 if no records found.
```

In SQL, it would be something like this,

```
SELECT TMain.counter as Age,
(SELECT Count(*) AS [Count]
FROM (SELECT Int(DateDiff("d", Clients.dob, now())/365.25) AS AgeNum 
FROM Clients)  AS [%$##@_Alias]
WHERE (TMain.counter = [%$##@_Alias].ageNum)
GROUP BY [%$##@_Alias].AgeNum) as number_of_clients
FROM (SELECT (T2.mAge*t3.mFactor10)+t1.mAge AS counter
FROM (select 1 as mAge from dual
union all select 2 from dual
union all select 3 from dual
union all select 4 from dual
union all select 5 from dual
union all select 6 from dual
union all select 7 from dual
union all select 8 from dual
union all select 9 from dual
union all select 10 from dual)  AS T1, 
(select 0 as mAge from dual
union all select 1 from dual
union all select 2 from dual
union all select 3 from dual
union all select 4 from dual
union all select 5 from dual
union all select 6 from dual
union all select 7 from dual
union all select 8 from dual
union all select 9 from dual
union all select 10 from dual)  AS T2,
(select 10 as mFactor10 from dual) AS T3 )  AS TMain
WHERE (((TMain.counter) Between 1 And 100));
```

this will produce: age from 1..100 as well as number of clients for each age and null for null/empty no results .
of course, you can dynamically extend or shorten the age list.

Comment: This worked well. However, I need to add in zeros for all of the blank rows. Sergey S suggested the Nz function. I tried adding it in on this line:

Comment: just encapsulate the entire sub-query.. nz((select count(.....),0) as ageNum @BeakerMcChemist

Comment: This worked well. However, I need to add in zeros for all of the blank rows because the agency we are reporting to is very strict on how things are formatted. @Sergey-S and @onedaywhen suggested the Nz function. I tried adding it in on this line:  `GROUP BY [Alias].AgeNum) as number_of_clients`    I changed it to `GROUP BY Nz([Alias].AgeNum,0)) as number_of_clients` but it didn't work. The query feeds into a report generated by Access.This is my first time using Access.  I was chosen to do this because I "know computers" but I am in way over my head.

Answer (score 0):

You can use instead of `COALESCE` `Nz` function:

```
Nz([Age],0)
```

And yes, your link should work for you.

Comment: TC said, that he works with Access and he needs query. Nz finction supported in Access queries

Comment: "Nz finction supported in Access queries" - Not strictly correct: Nz expression (not strictly a function when used in queries) is supported in Access queries only when that query is executed within the Access user interface. They say the are using "an Access 2010 database" then allude to "the required report" but doesn't explicitly state they are using the Access UI. You probably assume correctly though :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a 'sequence' table of all possible integers (FYI in UK medical data dictionaries we use 220 as the maximum age in years), then 'anti-join' to this table. You could use a view for your original results.

The following SQL DDL requires ANSI-92 Query Mode (probably better for the SQL Server coder than the default Query Mode) but can also be created maually using the Access GUI tools:

```
CREATE TABLE Seq ( seq INT NOT NULL UNIQUE );


INSERT INTO Seq VALUES ( 1 );
INSERT INTO Seq VALUES ( 2 );
INSERT INTO Seq VALUES ( 3 );
...
(you can use Excel to create this script!)
...
INSERT INTO Seq VALUES ( 100 );


CREATE VIEW ClientAgeTallies ( AgeInYears, Tally )
AS
SELECT dt.AgeInYears, COUNT(*) AS Tally
  FROM ( SELECT INT(DATEDIFF( 'd', c.dob, NOW() ) / 365.25) AS AgeInYears
           FROM Clients AS c ) AS dt
 GROUP 
    BY dt.AgeInYears;


SELECT AgeInYears, Tally
  FROM ClientAgeTallies
UNION
SELECT seq AS AgeInYears, 0 AS Tally
  FROM Seq
 WHERE seq NOT IN ( SELECT AgeInYears FROM ClientAgeTallies );
```