# Sql query to return missing rows as NaN from Where IN clause, using matlab odbc

Tags: sql, matlab, ms-access

I have an ms access database with table DATA as follows

```
DATE       | SYMBOL |  CLOSE |
01/01/99      ABC      10.00
01/02/99      ABC      13.00
01/07/99      ABC      20.00
01/12/99      ABC      22.00
01/30/99      ABC      39.00
01/01/99      XYZ      11.00
01/02/99      XYZ      14.00
01/07/99      XYZ      17.00
01/12/99      XYZ      19.00
01/30/99      XYZ      21.20
```

And using matlab I would like to select all close values for which their corresponding dates match my 'dates of interest' for a given symbol, so I use an query as follows:

```
sqlquery = ['select CLOSE from DATA where DATE in (' dates ') and SYMBOL = 'ABC'];
```

where

```
dates = '#01/01/99#,#01/02/99#,#01/03/99#,#01/04/99#,#01/05/99#,#01/06/99#,#01/07/99#';
```

The issue I am facing is such that if I am asking for a CLOSE value corresponding to a query date which does not exist as a record for the given symbol, I would like to receive a null value for CLOSE where a record is missing (the current query does not do this). Ultimately in my program I would like to take the response from my query and copy it into an array for the symbol as follows:

```
01/01/99 | 10.00 |   
01/02/99 | 13.00 |      
01/03/99 |  NaN  |  
01/04/99 |  NaN  |
01/05/99 |  NaN  |
01/06/99 |  NaN  |
01/07/99 | 20.00 |
```

Is there a way to accomplish this response data via an sql query?

Comment: I reckon you need a calendar table, such a table is very useful and light-weight.

Answer (score -1):

You need to provide the date range you are searching for before you can find if there are empty rows or not.

very similar question and answers can be found here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/39791046/1684486