# SQL Server : resultset zero totals for values that don't exist

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/85aa1/15)

I'm trying to force through zero values for grades that don't exist in my `Results` table, but do exist in my list of possible `Grades` table.

I've managed to join tables successfully in order to almost achieve this using [this previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27162465/how-can-i-create-a-row-for-values-that-dont-exist-and-fill-the-count-with-0-val) as guidance up to a point.

As you can see from my fiddle the resultset is displaying NULL values for my `Year` and `Subject` columns and I would like these to display the relevant subject.

Comment: Perhaps LEFT JOIN?

Comment: @jarlh thanks, but the fiddle already uses a left join.

Comment: Your fiddle is using MySQL... Switch to SQL Server if that's what you're using.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `*` in `SELECT` instead use specify the colums you need and use `ISNULL` and make it as zero like:

```
SELECT ISNULL(t.amount,0)
FROM [yourtable] y
left join [someOtherTable] t
ON y.id=t.id
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a table of Subjects and Years, then cross join for grades...

```
create table Subjects(SubjectID INT, Subject Varchar(50));
create table YearSub (SubjectID INT, Year INT, CrateDate Date); -- Map your available subjects for each year in here
```

Once you have thiese, make a CTE to hold the full list of available subjects, years and grades

```
with AllGrades as
(select SubjectID, Year, Grade
 from YearSub YS
 cross join Grades
)
select ... 
from AllGrades
left join ...
```

And so on

Answer (score 0):

i think this is what you wanted.

first you get all combinition of student & grades by using CROSS JOIN

then you LEFT JOIN to the resutl table to the get the count

```
select s.year, subject grade, grade, count(wag) as Total 
from   student s 
cross join grades g
left join results r on s.upn = r.upn and s.upn = r.upn
group by s.year, g.grade
```